# Reposting Latin questions from linguistics.se which could be answered better here

Tags: discussion

Given an already-answered question on Latin posted on Linguistics SE which a user believes might be better answered on Latin SE, is it bad form to repost the question on Latin SE?

Comment: I'm not a super-experienced SEer, but I myself would not object to this.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest we do what is common practice between [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).
Between those sites cross-posting is usually allowed, but only if these conditions are satisfied:

- The two posts are clearly linked to each other.
  This makes it easy for other users to check if the question has already been answered and avoid duplicate efforts.
- The two posts are not posted simultaneously.
  One should first ask on one of the sites, and if there is no answer in a week or so, the question can be asked on the other site.
  Cross-posting within a day or so is typically strongly frowned upon.
- The two posts are on-topic on their sites.
  This includes adapting the question to different audiences.

I consider it very bad manners to ask an identical question on several sites at the same time with no indication of duplication — especially if the OP demands an immediate answer.
This network is not an instant answer service.
Putting some effort into the questions and waiting long enough is more in the spirit of what this system is built for.

It might happen that a question on Linguistics yields an answer that is not satisfactory from a Latinist's point of view (or the other way around).
Then asking a more Latin-oriented follow-up question on this site might be a good idea, but the new question benefits from the OP having learned something from the earlier question on the other site.

If it seems that an unanswered question at Linguistics might get an answer here, I suggest cross-posting and linking after waiting a while.
One might be tempted to delete the old post, but it does still serve a purpose: it makes the question easier to find and advertises our site.

---

Some posts on MathOverflow meta about cross-posting:

- [Cross posts to Math SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637/55893)
- [Close cross posts between here and MSE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/423/55893)
- [the correct way to “cross-post”?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1725/55893)
- [How to respond to premature crossposts from Math.SE?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2087/55893)