# Would a question about an uncertain passage in a Greek poem (e.g. Sappho) be accepted here (at least while Greek SE is not graduated)?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, greek

I once translated (and thus had to reconstruct, in part) the complete poems of Sappho. I am now posting those translations to my blog, along with other translations. As I will have to go over the reconstruction part, I might find some old critical questions such as [this one I asked on Quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Who-proposed-version-A-of-this-line-of-Sappho%E2%80%99s-Ode-to-Anaktoria-see-screenshot-in-details-where-why-and-how-supported-is-this-idea), and I was wondering if such a discussion would be accepted here. Since the language Sappho used is Greek, I figured Greek Language would be the best fit, except it's still in commitment (35%) at the time of writing the question. I asked on main meta, and I was pointed to this site, with advice to ask on this meta before posting.

So I was wondering: Would it be appropriate to post them here in the meantime (i.e. while Greek Language finishes commitment and enters Private Beta)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, for the time being questions about Ancient Greek are allowed here. If you're interested, our policy for the time being is explained here:

[What should we do with Greek questions?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218/what-should-we-do-with-greek-questions?rq=1)

Your question does sound very subtle and complicated, so you'll have to be lucky to be spotted by a Sapphic scholar or someone else who can figure it out. It is a very interesting question and I would certainly welcome it here! Good luck.

Comment: I opted for [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/about-l-3-of-the-second-stanza-of-sapphos-%e1%bd%a8%ce%b4%e1%bd%b4-%ce%b5%e1%bc%b0%cf%82-%e1%bc%88%ce%bd%ce%b1%ce%ba%cf%84%cf%89%cf%81%ce%af%ce%b1%ce%bd-ode-to-anactoria) in the end.

Comment: @MickG That's a shame. It would be largely unappreciated there, while it's perfectly fine here.

Comment: @CMWelmer +11 and an enthusiastic comment («Welcome to Literature, MickG, and thanks for this great question! I hope you find a satisfying answer :)») is not exactly "largely unappreciated", right :)?

Comment: `questions about Ancient Greek are allowed here` Does that include Koine Greek?

Answer (score 6):

Some of the Sapphic questions have already been asked at another SE site, but that does not prevent from asking them here, too.
However, such cross posting should be done with care.
See [an older meta discussion about cross posting](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/159/79) for more.

Since the proposed question would be on-topic, I favor cross posting, but under the following conditions:

1. Let the old question be around for at least a week or so. That gives users at the other site plenty of time to react and give feedback. Also, you want to avoid giving the impression of copying the same question to many sites simultaneously in the hope of at least one quick answer. Many will frown upon such shotgun behavior.
2. Tailor the new question to the new audience, if possible. I don't know what that would mean in this case, but do notice that the audience is different. Also, copying and pasting the question may give an impression of zero effort and make people frown upon it.
3. If you learned anything from comments or partial answers from the other site, take it into account and edit accordingly. Consider restructuring, for example splitting a long question in individually answerable pieces asked separately. If people seemed to misunderstand you, consider rephrasing.
4. Link the questions to each other so they are easy to find. Don't just comment, but edit the questions to include clear links for everyone to see. This will make any insights or information easy to find across the sites.